# XCode Show Focus Ring

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I have a NSButton in my XCode project which gets enabled and disabled.

When it gets enabled, the user doesn't really notice, nothing stands out, the text just goes from grey to black.

What I'd like to happen, is to manually show the button's focus ring, or any other type of highlight when the button gets enabled. I've looked online and I can't find anything, leaving me to think it can't be done?

Can anyone help?

I'd imagine it'd be something as simple as:

```
[myButton setFocusRing:visible];
```

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

```
[window makeFirstResponder:theButton];
```

should do it.

Comment: That's not working for me, I enable the button first and then change the focus if that makes any difference?

Comment: I do the same and it works fine here in a sample project. Does the call to [window makeFirstResponder:theButton] return YES in your code?

Comment: It does return YES, but the button is not highlighted

Comment: Sorry, I really don't have a clue. You haven't set your button's focus ring to none in IB?

Comment: I think the focus ring only shows if Full Keyboard Access->All Controls in system settings is enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Change following setting.Go to System Preferences >> Keyboard >> Shortcuts tab >>Enable "All controls" radio button in bottom left corner.